# How do I delete all but the newest 20 rows in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

How do you delete the top row?  I want to delete the top row if theres more than 20 rows.
im using c#.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

> **TOP (expression) [ PERCENT ]**
>
> Specifies the number or percent of
>   random rows that will be deleted.
>   expression can be either a number or a
>   percent of the rows. The rows
>   referenced in the TOP expression used
>   with INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE are not
>   arranged in any order.

Maybe also have a read at [The DELETE statement in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-delete-statement-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Some info about deletion http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx

```
var ordFetch =
    (from ofetch in db.Orders
     where ofetch.OrderID == reqOrder
     select ofetch).First();
db.Orders.DeleteOnSubmit(ordFetch);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

To select top rows:

```
var data = (from p in people
           select p).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID field is a suitable substitute and always increases with time (i.e., smallest values of ID are the oldest, and that is always the case):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(
        "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 20 ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC)");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(My C# syntax may be slightly off -- I did this from memory -- but the SQL query should be fine.)